# Order by a linked objects attribute when the linked object's FK could be null?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table that is linked to an another table with a foreign key field and the field itself is nullable. That means a row in a first table may or may not have a corresponding row in another.

For the sake of simplicity let's name the first table `Foo` and the second `Bar`.

Now when I query rows from `Foo` and try to order them by a field from `Bar` like this:

```
FROM Foo ORDER BY Bar.name
```

The result shows only these values from `Foo` where the field `bar_id` is not null. What is the best possible way to also include these rows from `Foo`, which don't have a corresponding row in `Bar`.

Currently I have a big and sloppy method which takes values from filterMap and sortMap and appends them to a `StringBuffer` resulting a HQL query.

I have heard something about Criteria API but don't know if it can help me past this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a left join rather than an inner join:

```
select foo from Foo foo left join foo.bar bar order by bar.name
```